# particular Data not getting inserted in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a unknown problem while I go insert data.Some data getting inserted in same table n same column but except one.

The following is my code.

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

include("index.php");
?>
<form action="addcenter.php" method="post">
<table align="center" border="9" width="600">
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="5" bgcolor="yellow">
<h1>Add Your Center Details</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>District Name</th>
<td><input type="text" name="district"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Phone No.</th>
<td><input type="text" name="phone"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Person's Name</th>
<td><input type="text" name="person"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>Designation</th>
<td><input type="text" name="designation"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="5"><input type="submit" name="submit" 
value="submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>



<?php
include("includes/connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$district=$_POST['district'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$person=$_POST['person'];
$designation=$_POST['designation'];
if($district=='' or $phone=='' or $person=='' or $designation='')
{
    echo"<script> alert('Please fill the fiels')</script> ";
    exit();
}
$query="insert into centers (District,Phone,ContactPerson,Designation) 
values('$district','$phone','$person','$designation') ";
if(mysql_query($query))
{
    echo"<center><h1>Details Successfully added to your database</h1>
</center> ";
}

}
?>

 <table width=" 900" align="center" border="3">
 <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="9" bgcolor="orange"><h1>View all 
Centers</h1></td>
</tr>
<tr align="center">
 <th>SL No.</th>
 <th>District</th>
 <th>Phone No</th> 
 <th>Contact Person</th>
 <th>Designation</th>
 <th>Edit</th>
 <th>Delete</th>
 </tr>

<?php




$query="select * from centers";
$run=mysql_query($query);
$i=1;

while($row=(mysql_fetch_array($run)))
{

   $center_id=$row['center_id'];
$district=$row['District'];
$phone=$row['Phone'];
$contact_person=$row['ContactPerson'];
$designation=$row['Designation'];

?>
<tr align="center">
   <td><?php echo $i++ ;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $district;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $phone ;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $contact_person ;?></td>
   <td><?php echo $designation ;?></td>
   <td><a href="editcenter.php?editcenter=<?php echo $center_id;?>">Edit</a>
</td>
   <td><input type="button" onclick="deleteme1(<?php echo $center_id ?>)" 
name="delete" value="Delete"></td>
 </tr>
 <script language="javascript">
 function deleteme1(delid1)
 {
     if(confirm("are u sure"))
     {
         window.location.href='deletecenter.php?del_id1='+delid1+'';
        return true;

     }
 }

 </script>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I going to insert the Contactperson,district,designation and phone no.Then only the data of Contactperson,district and phone no get inserted but not the designation..I dont know why this is happening even the coding is also right..Please help me. Thankyou

Comment: Please edit your question to only have the part of your code which is relevant. It is hard to figure out what is specifically going wrong when you post your entire script.

Comment: Your code is suseptable to SQL injection. Use the mysqli functions instead of mysql functions. Also, use parameterized queries. Do you have error reporting turned on? Are you seeing any errors? You might try echoing the values of what is posted to be sure you're receiving what is entered in the fields.

Comment: Show your database schema !!
I think your problem is in the structure of your table

Answer (score 1):

Your "if" statement is assigning '' to $designation.  Use '==' for comparison.

if($district=='' or $phone=='' or $person=='' or $designation**=**'')

The if statement says, "if $district is '' or $phone is '' or $person is '' or 'I can assign nothing to $designation (which always succeeds)' - at which point you have successfully assigned '' to $designation.  The if statement finishes and you insert '' into designation.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.. 

Comment: If you wouldn't mind accepting the solution, I'd appreciate it.